# Divisible Direct Sum or Direct Product

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

We know that direct sum and direct product of divisible R-modules are divisible when R is a *domain*. Does there exist non-divisible modules with their product or sum being divisible?
Or, if R is not a domain could one find an example of a divisible direct product or direct sum of divisible R-modules?
Thanks to any one answering the question.

Comment: I answered this here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/754954/583

Comment: (The answer is no: the direct sum is divisible iff the direct product is divisible iff each component is divisible; this is regardless of being a domain. Being a domain is only relevant to the other property mentioned by Lam: quotients.)